# How can I pass string param containing slash character in postman?

Tags: api, rest, postman

I have a scenario where I have to pass

```
https://domain/sample?sysparm_query=abc/def&sysparm_display_value=true
```

in postman. However I am not getting the desired answer. I even tried encoding `/` with `%2F`, but does not work.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with that character.

[image]